# Combining Image Histograms

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, histogram, matlab-figure

I just want to be able to create a combined histogram of three gray scaled images onto one histogram. When I run the code below, the x axis overlaps each histogram so essentially I have three identical x axes. I also want to be able to have different colors signaling the different pictures. here is my code:

```
subplot(4,3,1);
image1=imread('93-94_1-0-32(302).png');
imshow(image1);
gray1=rgb2gray(image1);

subplot(4,3,2);
image2=imread('90-91_1-0-32(101).png');
imshow(image2);
gray2=rgb2gray(image2);

subplot(4,3,3);
image3=imread('55-56_1.2-0-18(Sugar).png');
imshow(image3);
gray3=rgb2gray(image3);

subplot(4,3,[4,5,6]);
imhist(gray1);
hold on;
imhist(gray2);
hold on;
imhist(gray3);
```

Comment: How do you want those three histograms? Stacked vertically? As subplots? As lines (not bars) with different colors on the same graph?

Comment: I need them all on the same graph, so every bar of the three images will be on the same plot essentially. So just one histogram with lines of different colors pertaining to signals of each of the three images.

Comment: use `hold all` instead of `hold on`. Moreover, you only need to `hold all` once, no need to `hold all` after every `imhist` command.

Comment: I put hold all after enabling the subplot and that automatically changes the color of each imhist, but it does not get rid of the problem where there are three duplicated x-axes.

Comment: You could do your own histogram commands and then use `bar` (then look at 'grouped' or 'stacked', depending on what you want).

Comment: or you define yourself 3 x-axis, where 2 have no  values or ticks(Essentially deleting them) and one is as you want your x-axis. Check out the documentation of "axes" and the one of "set()"-function. This is a line of code I used (`set(gca, 'XTick',myxaxis, 'XTickLabel',mytimeline(myxaxis))`). Here `myxaxis` is an array which corresponds to the ticks i wanted to display and `mytimeline` was a string which I wanted as labels.